# Transformation of functions help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f:[0,4] \to\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=6\sin(\pi x/2)$

Let $h:[-3,1] \to\mathbb{R}$, $h(x)=6\cos(\pi x/2)$
State a sequence of two transformations that takes the graph of $f$ to the graph of $h$.

I would love some help on this because I am confused about how to go from graph $f$ to graph $h$. For example, I can only see one transformation to go from $f$ to $h$ which is changing sin to cos but I can't see a second transformation. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, stating that you are confused about the whole problem isn't really helpful for us to figure out how to help you. Please edit it in more context highlighting where in the process you got stuck, what example functions you looked at, what ideas you may have, etc.

Comment: What kinds of transformations are you allowed to use?

Comment: Any kind, this is for a class that is technology with math education and the prof wants us to solve it with and without technology and comment on it on how it assesses differently a student's mathematical knowledge but I can't even do that if I can't solve the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you do a single transformation, you shift the graph of the function to the left by $1$. I can think of several options:

1. Split the shift into two separate shifts, say by $0.2$ and $0.8$
2. Multiply $f$ by $-1$ and you need a shift by $3$
3. Shift by $1$ and change $x$ to $-x$. The last transformation should not change $h$